# How to start flyway script versions over

Tags: refactoring, flyway, refactoring-databases

My flyway scripts are getting a bit extensive, and it takes a while to wipe and recreate a schema.  It's getting unwieldy, and I figure others have hit this situation with flyway.

I would like to start the scripts over:  create a snapshot of the current database, give it a version one, and start over from there.

But for production databases, I'll never be wiping the schema, and I don't want it to parse through the history each time, and get conflicts on the version numbers.  I figure I will need to recreate the `schema_version` table, but it seems a bit finicky.  Has anyone done this, and could you give me instructions on your process?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you can do is

- dump your db structure, and give this the current version of your db (this will help you recreate it in dev)
- drop the schema_version table from prod
- flyway.init() prod with the version of the dump
- get rid of all previous migration scripts and keep only the dump